# encoding protein sequences into numeric vector using hydrophobicity

Tags: python

i am trying  code of python for encoding protein sequences into numeric vector using hydrophobicity. im trying to give numeric values to amino acid sequences but i got error of index out of range at for loop i dont know what to do kindly help
here is my coding

```
import csv

data= open('negative.fasta')

datacsvfile=csv.reader(data,delimiter=',')

sequenceData = list(datacsvfile)

output = open('seq.text', 'w')

csvWriter = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')

for row in range(len(sequenceData)):
    sequencecode=[]
    for item in range(len(sequenceData[row][2])):
        if sequenceData[row][2][item]=='L':
            sequencecode.append(0.0000)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='I':
            sequencecode.append(0.0000)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='N':
            sequencecode.append(0.0036)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='G':
            sequencecode.append(0.0050)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='V':
            sequencecode.append(0.0057)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='E':
            sequencecode.append(0.0058)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='P':
            sequencecode.append(0.0198)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='H':
            sequencecode.append(0.0242)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='K':
            sequencecode.append(0.0371)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='A':
            sequencecode.append(0.0373)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='Y':
            sequencecode.append(0.0516)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='W':
            sequencecode.append(0.0548)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='Q':
            sequencecode.append(0.0761)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='M':
            sequencecode.append(0.0823)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='S':
            sequencecode.append(0.0829)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='C':
            sequencecode.append(0.0829)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='T':
            sequencecode.append(0.0941)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='F':
            sequencecode.append(0.0954)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='R':
            sequencecode.append(0.0956)
        elif sequenceData[row][2][item]=='D':
            sequencecode.append(0.1263)
    csvWriter.writerow([sequenceData[row][0],sequenceData[row][1],sequencecode])
 

data.close()
output.close()
```

error is below. kindly help me to solve this error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-2334db331d8d> in <module>()
      1 for row in range(len(sequenceData)):
      2         sequencecode=[]
----> 3         for item in range(len(sequenceData[row][2])):
      4                 if sequenceData[row][2][item]=='L':
      5                         sequencecode.append(0.0000)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bioinformatician and I work with this kind of data from may years.

My hint is to optimize the algorithm to better perform on long sequences, especially when you have to analyze several hundreds of sequences. So instead of cycling you should use `numpy` and `pandas` library to get faster.

This is how I would solve your problem:

```
#first of read the fasta sequence
def read_fasta_seq(file):
    return "".join([line.strip() for line in open(file).readlines() if not line[0]==">"])
protein_str = read_fasta_seq("example.fasta")

#the library you need
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

now what you want is to convert the protein string in a array:

```
protein_arr = pd.Series(list(protein_str))
```

now define an aminoacid vocabulary and an encoding for that:

```
#vocabulary
aa = ["L", "I", "N", "G", "V", "E", "P", "H", "K", "A", "Y", "W", "Q", "M", "S", "C", "T", "F", "R", "D"]

#encoding
aa_encode = [
    0.0000,0.0000,0.0036,0.0050,0.0057,0.0058,0.0198,0.0242,0.0371,0.0373,
    0.0516,0.0548,0.0761,0.0823,0.0829,0.0829,0.0941,0.0954,0.0956,0.1263
]

aa_encoding_series = pd.Series(aa_encoding, index=aa)
```

The `aa_encoding_series` is a pandas series like this:

```
L    0.0000
I    0.0000
N    0.0036
G    0.0050
V    0.0057
E    0.0058
P    0.0198
H    0.0242
K    0.0371
A    0.0373
Y    0.0516
W    0.0548
Q    0.0761
M    0.0823
S    0.0829
C    0.0829
T    0.0941
F    0.0954
R    0.0956
D    0.1263
dtype: float64
```

now you can simply use this series to fast encode your `protein_arr` sequence as:

```
aa_encoding_series.loc[protein_arr].values
```

output:

```
array([0.    , 0.0516, 0.    , 0.    , 0.0954, 0.005 , 0.0373, 0.0548,
       0.0373, 0.005 , 0.0823, 0.0057, 0.005 , 0.0941, 0.0373, 0.    ,
       0.0829, 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.0956, 0.0373, 0.0058, 0.    ,
       0.005 , 0.0761, 0.0198, 0.005 , 0.0941, 0.    , 0.    , 0.005 ,
       0.1263, 0.1263, 0.0761, 0.    , 0.0516, 0.0036, 0.0057, 0.    ,
       0.0057, 0.0941, 0.0373, 0.0242, 0.0373, 0.0954, 0.0057, 0.0823,
       0.    , 0.0954, 0.0954, 0.0823, 0.0057, 0.0823, 0.0198, 0.    ,
       0.0823, 0.    , 0.005 , 0.005 , 0.0954, 0.005 , 0.0036, 0.0548,
       0.    , 0.0057, 0.0198, 0.    , 0.0823, 0.    , 0.005 , 0.0373,
       0.0198, 0.1263, 0.0823, 0.0373, 0.0954, 0.0198, 0.0956, 0.0823,
       0.0036, 0.0036, 0.0823, 0.0829, 0.0954, 0.0548, 0.    , 0.    ,
       0.0198, 0.0198, 0.0829, 0.0954, 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ,
       0.0373, 0.0829, 0.0829, 0.0941, 0.0057, 0.0058, 0.0373, 0.005 ,
       0.0373, 0.005 , 0.0941, 0.005 , 0.0548, 0.0941, 0.0057, 0.0516,
       0.0198, 0.0198, 0.    , 0.0373, 0.005 , 0.0036, 0.    , 0.0373,
       0.0242, 0.0373, 0.005 , 0.0373, 0.0829, 0.0057, 0.1263, 0.    ,
       0.0373, 0.    , 0.0954, 0.0829, 0.    , 0.0242, 0.    , 0.0373,
       0.005 , 0.0057, 0.0829, 0.0829, 0.    , 0.    , 0.005 , 0.0373,
       0.    , 0.0036, 0.0954, 0.    , 0.0941, 0.0941, 0.0373, 0.    ,
       0.0036, 0.0823, 0.0371, 0.0198, 0.0198, 0.0941, 0.    , 0.0829,
       0.0761, 0.0516, 0.0761, 0.0941, 0.0198, 0.    , 0.0954, 0.0057,
       0.0548, 0.0829, 0.0057, 0.    , 0.    , 0.0941, 0.0373, 0.0057,
       0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.0829, 0.    , 0.0198, 0.0057,
       0.    , 0.0373, 0.0373, 0.005 , 0.    , 0.0941, 0.0823, 0.    ,
       0.    , 0.0941, 0.1263, 0.0956, 0.0036, 0.    , 0.0036, 0.0941,
       0.0941, 0.0954, 0.0954, 0.1263, 0.0198, 0.0373, 0.005 , 0.005 ,
       0.005 , 0.1263, 0.0198, 0.0057, 0.    , 0.0516, 0.0761, 0.0242,
       0.    , 0.0954, 0.0548, 0.0954, 0.0954, 0.005 , 0.0242, 0.0198,
       0.0058, 0.0057, 0.0516, 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ])
```